# Node module for finding file paths with multiple possible roots

Tags: node.js

Is there a Node module which allows you to specify multiple roots, give it a file, and it tries to find the file?

A know a lot of libraries/modules do this sort of thing, but my Google-fu failed to turn up an existing module for it, which was kind of surprising.

To clarify, basically if I had some config like this:

```
roots: ['node_modules', 'bower_components', 'src']
```

And I asked it to find "my-file.js", it would search the following:

```
node_modules/my-file.js
bower_components/my-file.js
src/my-file.js
```

And return the first one that resolves to an existing file, or return an error saying it couldn't resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any library for this either, but what youre asking for can be done in a few lines of code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const roots = ['node_modules', 'bower_components', 'src'];
const myFile = 'my-file.js';
const result = roots.map(root => path.resolve(path.join(root,myFile))).map(fs.existsSync);
```

This will give you an array of true/false values corresponding to each element in `roots`. So if `src/my-file.js` and `node_modules/my-file.js` exist, you would get `result` as
`[true, false, true]`

Comment: Thanks. I actually wrote my own quick node module in about 5 minutes as well. I just like to do things with standard node modules when they exist, and since this is something so common, I thought it must exist. But, it might be because it is so simple, that everyone might just be coding i themselves.

Comment: True, but even the most simple things have node modules of their own ;) https://github.com/sindresorhus/ama/issues/10